# Error on loading data into variable from fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm trying to build a webpage using JS/HTML/CSS only (no frameworks), but when trying to assign the response into a variable, seems like the flow isn't in the order I've wrote:

```js
var COUNTRIES_DATA = "";

function fetchCountriesData(){
fetch(`${API_URL}/countries`).then(response => {
  return response.json().then(countries => {
    COUNTRIES_DATA = countries;
  });
});
};

fetchCountriesData();
renderCountriesCombo(COUNTRIES_DATA);


function renderCountriesCombo(countries) {
  countries.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a.Country > b.Country) ? 1 : ((b.Country > a.Country) ? -1 : 0);
  });
  let options = countries.map(country => {
    return `<option>${country.Country}</option>`
  })
  document.getElementById("combo").innerHTML = options;
}
```

The error message I'm getting is `countries.sort is not a function`, but when I debug the value of countries inside the `renderCountriesData()` the `countries` variable is empty.

Break points on ->

- `fetch('${API_URL}/countries').then`
- `fetchCountriesData();`
- `countries.sort(function (a, b) {`

The flow when I'm debbuging looks like:

starts on `fetchCountriesData()` -> since I've a `<body onload="fetchCountriesData()">`
goes the the function signature (1st line), doesn't run the `return` method,
next it goes to the `renderCountriesCombo()` function and give the error message, then goes back to the `fetchCountriesData()` and populate the `COUNTRIES_DATA`.

The problem is, that I need that `COUNTRIES_DATA` variable to be populated before any other method runs.

Comment: You should use conditionals at countries.sort.

Comment: First check if countries is there and then apply sort

Comment: @Irfanwani The main problem is that I just need the countries to be stored on a variable before everything starts to run, so I'll be able to treat the data whenever I need, without having the trouble to reach an API to fetch the data once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetch()` is network promise, after call promise the renderCountriesCombo is execute immediate, meanwhile the data is fetching, not completed.

you should do like this:

```
fetchCountriesData().then(countries => renderCountriesCombo(countries))
```

Comment: Yeah, that would totally work, but the main problem is that I need this info to be available on other parts of my code. In this schema I would have to fetch the api at least 2 more times. Store the value into a variable would be a better option for me.

Comment: you can make a `render()` function,  it responsible to render all ui need the data.

other option is use event model, make render function register a event, and fetch function emit the event after done